# Databricks auto merge schema

Tags: databricks

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

I have put the following before my merge, but it seems to not like it.

%sql set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled  = true

Also, the reason for putting this in was because my notebook was failing on schema changes to a delta lake table. I have an additional column on one of the tables I am loading into. I thought that data bricks were able to auto-merge schema changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine in my environment. I'm using Databricks runtime 10.4

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: add a semicolon to the end of the separate SQL statements:

```sql
set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled = true;
```

---

The error is actually a more generic SQL error; the `IllegalArgumentException` is a clue - though not a very helpful one :)

I was able to reproduce your error:

```sql
set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled = true

INSERT INTO records SELECT * FROM students
```

gives: `Error in SQL statement: IllegalArgumentException: spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled should be boolean, but was true`

and was able to fix it by adding a `;` to the end of the first line:

```sql
set spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled = true;

INSERT INTO records SELECT * FROM students
```

succeeds.

*Alternatively you could run the `set` in a different cell.*